# Fade out code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, fadeout

I am from a not developer background and I am making a WordPress webpage in divi theme for my photography thing.
I want a fade out element in the slider module. So what it does is when we scroll down the page the element moved up and fade out. Example like this: http://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/sfutl/

So I put this code (below) and got the desired effect:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
    <style>
        body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 1000px;
  }
   
  .top {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 100px;
  }
 </style>
 
     
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
 <script>
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 150);
        });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <div class="title">
    Fade Away
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

What I did, put the above codes in xyz Html(wordpress plugin) and get the Snippet Short Code and put this Snippet Short Code in the module.
But the issue is after the page loaded. The header transition/effect on scrolling to the logo is gone and I am not able see my logo on scrolling (center inline logo header style).
Can someone please help me to resolve this issue. A flow/steps/procedure to do the fade-out effect will help me a lot.

Comment: Everywhere you've used `$`, replace it with `jQuery` instead, as in `jQuery(window).scroll(...` etc.

Comment: Please take some time and format the code right, without that extra tabs.

Comment: @adeneo thanks bro.. finally it worked..

Comment: Hey need one more help what if i want to control the scrolling speed what need to be done. could anyone help me out??